# Colocar selected al primer option de un array dinamico vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

estoy haciendo un select con diferentes option traidos con un for en vue

```
<select name="" id="allValueExchange" v-model="currencyFinal">
      <option v-for="[key, value] of Object.entries(currencyExchange).slice(1)" :value="[key, value]">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

Quiero que quede con select el primer elemento option de la lista, pero no se como hacerlo, trate con jquery de esta manera y no me funciono. Alguna idea?

```
$('select option:first-child').attr("selected", "selected")
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede usar la directiva `selected` en el option aplicando un boolean para usar el primer elemento por default:

```
:selected="key === Object.keys(currencyExchange)[0]
```